# Can not return back with Espresso.pressBack() after open a PDF

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to test my app with Espresso.

I have a problem: in one use case, i need to open a PDF for reading "User conditions" and i can not return back from this point with Espresso.pressBack(), always i have the error below:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you t to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
 at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
 at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError (DefaultFailureHandler.java:88)
 at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
 at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
 at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:173)
 at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:114)
 at android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.pressBack(Espresso.java:220)
```

Any suggested solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:$uiAutomatorVersion')
}
```

And then simply:

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
device.pressBack()
```

*This should be included in espresso I believe, no sense to have it as separate thing.*

Answer (score 0):

That is caused because you can't use Espresso out of the app that you are testing. So you can only use Espresso.pressBack() when you are in the main app.

If you have to interact with activities out of your main app, I suggest you using UIAutomator2, it allows you interact with other apps and you can introduce it in a Espresso test with no problems.